# declaring a template method for a template class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I'm trying to declare a template method on a template class and it's not working for me.
It's better to explain by giving the code so here it is:
I have this class:

> matrix.h

```
template <class T,int a,int b>
class Matrix {
private:
   int x;
   int y;
public:
   class IllegalOperation();
   template<T,int c,int d>
   Matrix<T,a,b> operator+(const Matrix<T,c,d> m);
   //...
}
```

> matrix.cpp

```
template<class T,int a,int b>
template<T,int c,int d>
Matrix<T,a,b> Matrix<T,a,b>::operator+(const Matrix<T,c,d> m){
  if(a!=c || b!=d) throw IllegalOperation();
  // add matrices and return the result
}
```

I'd like this code to work for any 2 types of Matrix and Matrix where a,b,c and d can be different.
for example, I want this code to **compile** and return an error (in run time):

```
const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m1;
const Matrix<int, 7, 3> m2;
// init m1 and m2
m1+m2;
```

While this code should **compile** and run successfully:

```
const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m1;
const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m2;
// init m1 and m2
m1+m2;
```

However, when I try to compile the code above I get this error:

> no match for âoperator+ in m1+m2

Comment: You want `operator+` to be able to add only matrices _of the same size_, but contradict yourself by using `Matrix<T, c, d>` as its argument, where `c` and `d` may not be equal to `a` and `b` respectively.

Comment: Besides that error you currently have, you should know about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @ForceBru I'm not contradicting myself, BUT I want the error to be shown in runtime and not in compile time. I want the code to compile and then give me the error.

Comment: "I want the error to be shown in runtime and not in compile time" Don't make the matrix size a template parameter then.

Comment: @Loay _" I think in my case it's to separate the implementation."_ Well, that would simply not work :-P

Comment: @n.m. it's an assignment, I have to do it this way :)

Comment: Is this "error to be shown in runtime" a required part of the assignment? Please quote the assignment verbatim in your question, and also provide a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. "Is this "error to be shown in runtime" a required part of the assignment? " - yes it is, I'm supposed to throw an exception. I don't know why you need this to answer the question but I'll edit the post

Comment: This is a rather unusual and senseless requirement that suggests that your instructor doesn't necessarily have a clue. I would rather not assume that without sufficient evidence. This means I want to **read the assignment itself** rather than your interpretation of it, which may or may not be correct.

Comment: @n.m. yeah I agree with you but this is what he wants. besides, since it's unusual, it's good to know and learn :D

Comment: You want to **quote the requirements verbatim** and also emphasize the unusual part, because everyone who is going to read your question will first assume that you are mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this (not considering the things that I think might be wrong here, only changed it to make it compile)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,int a,int b>
class Matrix {
public:
    template<typename T2, int c, int d>
    Matrix<T,a,b> operator+(const Matrix<T2, c, d>& m) const;
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

template <typename T,int a,int b>
template <typename T2, int c, int d>
Matrix<T, a, b> Matrix<T, a, b>::operator+(const Matrix<T2, c, d>&) const {
    if(a != c || b != d) {
        throw IllegalOperation{};
    }
    /*constexpr*/ if (!std::is_same<T, T2>::value) {
        throw Error{};
    }
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m1{};
    const Matrix<int, 7, 3> m2{};
    m1 + m2;
    return 0;
}
```

I've made a few changes here

1. The `operator+` is `const`, you were trying to call a non const member function on a const object, would not work
2. The matrix parameter in the addition operator is now taken by reference
3. The `operator+` cannot be defined in the `.cpp` file as mentioned in the comments, it must go in the header file (if you want to split up the interface and implementation, the best you can do is [In the C++ Boost libraries, why is there a ".ipp" extension on some header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543507/in-the-c-boost-libraries-why-is-there-a-ipp-extension-on-some-header-files))
4. I usually like having the `public` section first since it gives the reader a better idea about the interface of the class.

Comment: What would you do when T and T2 are different types?

Comment: @n.m. You mean in the `operator+` member?  Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, e,g, what happens when you add `Matrix<int,2,2>` and `Matrix<double,2,2>`? Returning `*this` would compile, but what about an actual addition?

Comment: @n.m.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  OP was having issues with getting code to compile so that's what I fixed.  But I can imagine a scenario where that is appropriate, for example if you have `int` and `short`.  OP will have to add constraints to that template later on if they want to be more general.

Comment: @Curious thank you for answering but as n.m said, the code would compile if T and T2 are different types. I'd like to throw an exception in this case.

Comment: @Loay ah, that's what you both meant, I updated the answer to include that.

Comment: @Loay keep in mind that usually these sorts of errors are supposed to be caught at compile time in C++.

Comment: @Loay you check that, but you should do that **if and only if this is explicitly spelled out in the assignment**. Otherwise, remove the T2 argument from the inner template altogether.